# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library sunmscapi.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following scenario: a Java Desktop application which invokes a Java Legacy class using Reflection. The legacy module executes some native operations (access to Smart Card). 
Everything works fine when running on Eclipse: I have my Java Desktop application as a Java project which has a set of libraries including the Java legacy JAR file. 
Now I have created a runnable JAR file from the Eclipse project: when I try to access the Java Legacy layer, the following error is issued: **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library sunmscapi.dll already loaded in another classloader** 
What really puzzles me is why it works correctly on Eclipse, which is using the same JDK settings as the runnable JAR file ??? any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Eclipse is not executing a runnable JAR file when launching application, but just adding the single classpath entries (see the .classpath file). Try to export the Desktop application ONLY in the jar file and then add all the other libs (incuding the legacy app) with -classpath. Then you have the same environment as Eclipse and they should not differ in the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By unpackaging the runnable JAR files in a folder and adding -classpath worked!